# Showing a div when an image in a slider is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a plugin image slider and am attempting to show specific text that will be associated with image. For instance, image 1 will show paragraph 1, image 2 will show paragraph 2, etc.

I was going to upload a snippet showing what I am doing, but the plugin code was too much. Therefore, here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2oanmpv/4/) link that shows what I am doing. The main code in question is at the bottom of the javascript and the text that I want to show is at the bottom of the html. This code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ma5slider').ma5slider();
        var court = $('#slide-1');
        var activeSlide = $('.slide--active') == true;
            if(court == activeSlide) {
                court.show();
          console.log('It is working');
                }
    });
```

I have the text set at `display: none;` on page load and then when the specific image is displaying (I believe I narrowed this down to the class `.slide--active`), that text set to `show()`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not targeting the right active class when each slide takes turn to slide in, I have amended your code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ma5slider').ma5slider();
        var court = $('.slide');
        var activeSlideClassName = 'slide--active';

        setInterval(function(){ 

          if(court.hasClass(activeSlideClassName)){
            console.log('It is working');
          }

        }, 1000);

});
```

Also your slide will need to have a callback function to capture the event whenever the new slide comes in. In this case I have used `setInterval()` to monitor the DOM, it isn't the best solution but you get the idea....

Working code [here](https://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/dVJaap)

Comment: Thank you for this. Not all slides will have the same content though. That is why I did `#slide-1`, but I just noticed that I wrote that in my own html in the `a href`. Is there a way to target each individual `a href`?

Comment: @Paul you could try `if ($('a').attr('href') === "the href you want"){ execute} `

Comment: @paul it might be not what you are asking for, it is just something i got while fixing your code https://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/ZXvPQz, you can use this to add individual caption for your slides

Comment: @paul, Shadow Fiend has answered your question regards to targeting the href

Comment: @Vincent1989 I actually think your method will be best for this, so I am trying to do your method. I have the `console.log` method working, but now I am trying to print the caption text to the div `#captionText`, but am unsuccessful. I am not sure how I can `show()` my `capText` variable. https://jsfiddle.net/h2oanmpv/11/

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. I had a brainfart. I appreciate all of the help!

Comment: you can try replacing capText.show(); with $('#captionText').html(capText);

Answer (score 1):

you can check it `$('.ma5slider').on('ma5.activeSlide')` same as below : 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2oanmpv/7/)